# Distribution of Hexagon Slices with equivalent perimeters?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

A regular hexagon is divided into four trapezoids and one hexagon. Each of the five sections has the same perimeter. Find the ratio of the lengths p, q, and r?
[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say our hexagon has side length $L$.  Let $\ell_1$ be the shorter horizontal segment inside the hexagon, $\ell_2$ the longer segment.  If we place an equilateral triangle with side length $L$ on top of our hexagon, we see that $\ell_1$ serves as the base of a larger equilateral triangle.  The other two sides of this triangle clearly have length $L+p$, so $|\ell_1|=L+p$, where $|\ell_1|$ is the length of $\ell_1$.  Similarly, $|\ell_2|=L+p+q$.  We can now compute the three relevant perimeters:
\begin{align*}
P_1 &= L + 2p + |\ell_1| = 3p+2L\\
P_2 &= |\ell_1|+2q+|\ell_2| = 2p+3q+2L\\
P_3 &= 4r + 2|\ell_2| = 2p+2q+4r+2L.
\end{align*}
Now since $P_1=P_2$ we have $3p+2L=2p+3q+2L$, so $p=3q$.  Next, $P_1=P_3$ gives
\begin{equation}
3p+2L = 2p+2q+4r+2L
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
p = 2q+4r
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
3q=2q+4r,
\end{equation}
so $q=4r$.  This means that $p=12r$, so we can write
\begin{equation}
p+q+r=L
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
12r+4r+r = L.
\end{equation}
We conclude that $p=\frac{12}{17}L$, $q=\frac{4}{17}L$, and $r=\frac{1}{17}L$.